# Java Servlet with Sql 2008 DB is not working

Tags: java, sql, database

I have installed tomcat 7.0.42 using Xampp. And i'm trying to add the data collected from an html page into database. The code is getting compiled correctly. But i'm getting Confused in execution. Please give me step by step execution steps. I have created the db and the dsn. The code is as follows.

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class login extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        String name , pass;
        name = req.getParameter("txtuname");
        pass = req.getParameter("txtpass");

            res.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();

        try
        {   
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:shri_dsn");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into login_db(uname,password)values('"+name+"','"+pass+"')");
            pw.println(" Data Inserted !");
            con.close();
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            pw.println(" You're Lost !");
        }
    }
}
```

The html code is as follows..

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name="login" method="post" action="../servlets/login" align="center">
        Username: <input type="text" name="txtuname" /> <br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="txtpass" /> <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="sumbit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have placed both java and html inside tomcat/webapps/hello. Please tell if it's correct.. and how to execute it?

Comment: this might help http://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-connect-to-the-database-in-java

Comment: Is this a MySQL database you are connecting to?

Comment: There could be >100 reasons. Don't skip the exception. Check it and print here the stack trace to let us see what exactly wrong with *your* code.

Comment: There are no errors in the code. The only thing is i think i'm executing it wrong. I'm getting 404 page not found error.

Comment: If you get a 404 response your code is not even executed. You need to fix that first.

Comment: Btw, MySQL != SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution finally. The action path i had set was wrong: the correct one was

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/sample/servlets/login" align="center">
```